# In which case DNS uses TCP port 53

Tags: dns

"Does DNS uses TCP port 53 also? If yes then in which scenario"

Comment: In `/etc/services file , there are two port entries for dns , it usually use udp 53 but not sure about tcp 53 , may be in some special cases`

Comment: Zone transfers. UDP is for regular lookups since they happen all the time and don't represent a lot of data (versus entire zones which can get pretty big).

Comment: This isn't a UNIX question though.

Comment: @Bratchley I do agree this is not a Unix question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Networking and has nothing to do with Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

It's used as a retry when the response exceeds the maximum size - particularly relevant if EDNS is not supported.

Comment: I would have answered more generally, potentially any time it cannot use UDP. Maybe it's a firewall problem, or a bad connection, an ssh tunnel (tcp-only), etc.

Comment: I wouldn't answer that because I don't know that's what happens. `dig` doesn't, perhaps you have a different example. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/313fb2008233a7cfc0dc041ec9e94c41

Comment: Well, I cannot know of every client and resolver, so I would say it generally. And dig says things like that in the man page too, `+[no]ignore
           Ignore truncation in UDP responses instead of retrying with TCP. By default, TCP retries are performed.`

Comment: Truncation occurs if and only if "the response exceeds the maximum size", no?

Comment: yes but I mean this is dig... some other client might have a totally different implementation.

Answer (score 2):

DNS queries consist of a single UDP request from the client followed by a single UDP reply from the server. The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) is used when the response data size exceeds 512 bytes, or for tasks such as zone transfers.

```
Most DNS [RFC1034] transactions take place over UDP [RFC768].  TCP
[RFC793] is always used for full zone transfers (using AXFR) and is
often used for messages whose sizes exceed the DNS protocol's
original 512-byte limit.  The growing deployment of DNS Security
(DNSSEC) and IPv6 has increased response sizes and therefore the use
of TCP.  The need for increased TCP use has also been driven by the
protection it provides against address spoofing and therefore
exploitation of DNS in reflection/amplification attacks.  It is now
widely used in Response Rate Limiting [RRL1] [RRL2].  Additionally,
recent work on DNS privacy solutions such as [DNS-over-TLS] is
another motivation to revisit DNS-over-TCP requirements.
```

Reference: [DNS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7766)